# Set only adding first element in C++

Tags: c++, set

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Tuple : public vector<string> {
private:
    vector <string> values; //hold values
public:
    Tuple(){};
    ~Tuple(){};

    void add(string val);
    void print();
};

void Tuple::add(string val) {
    values.push_back(val);
}
void Tuple::print() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        cout << values[i] << "\t";
    }
}

int main() {
set<Tuple> temp;
Tuple t1, t2, t3;
t1.add("a");
t1.add("b");
t2.add("c");
t2.add("d");
t3.add("c");
t3.add("a");
temp.insert(t1);
temp.insert(t2);
temp.insert(t3);

set<Tuple>::iterator it;
cout << temp.size() << endl;
for (it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++) {
    Tuple temp = *it;
    temp.print();
}
return 0;
}
```

and it outputs the following:

```
1
a    b
```

A tuple, is more or less a vector of strings. I know that sets don't allow duplicates, but am somewhat confused as to why it won't ad "c  d" or "c  a" since those are unique.

Comment: What's `Tuple`, how is the comparison operator defined with it`?

Comment: A tuple is a class I declared, that has a private member of a vector of strings. I have not defined any comparison operators, but I think it has to do with the '<' operator.

Comment: Why don't you simply do std::cout << temp.size() to check the set size. Most likely you have a problem with Tuple comparison operator...

Comment: @DavisPearson _"but I think it has to do with the '<' operator."_ Very probable, yes. Please edit your question an show at least the declaration of `Tuple`.

Comment: I am not sure why there is such a downpour of down-votes... The question just lacks the definition of `Tuple` and it was requested. Give the OP chance...

Comment: @jpo38 temp.size() returns 1

Comment: @DavisPearson I would be best if you provided whole example that can be compiled.

Comment: Your inheriting from `std::vector` (why?) makes all your objects compare equal.

Comment: Possible conflict with [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `std::vector<std::string>` and containing `std::vector<string>`?  You have added a second dimension; a string of a vector of strings.

Comment: Your `Tuple` class doesn't add any new functionality to `vector<string>`.

Comment: Your program gets strange.  Not only is `Tuple` 2 dimensional, but in your `main` function, you are creating a `set` of `Tuple`, thus creating a 3 dimensional structure of strings.

Comment: Inheriting from `std::vector` is just wrong. You are not supposed to inherit from classes that are not designed to be base classes. C++ containers have a complete different design philosophy than, say, Java containers.

Answer (score 3):

You're inheriting from `vector<string>`, and you also have a member `vector<string>` object.  Now the problem is that your `add` function appends to the member object. But your comparison operator is the one defined by the standard library, and acts on the base vector. It doesn't know anything about your member vector. So all your objects are considered empty (and therefore equal to each other) by `operator<`. Consequently, `set` considers them all equal, and so will not insert any after the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a *tuple* as a vector of strings, maybe the easiest solution is to use a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> Tuple;
```

This will allow you to use all the functionality of a vector of strings without having to write new code.

BTW, `std::vector` does have the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) overloaded.

Comment: Solved the issue by implementing Tuple as a vector